# CakePHP authentication breaking after an incorrect login

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have a simple login form, username and password. Basically, When a user is anywhere on the website, he can click a link that will take him to the login page. After login, he is redirected to the page he came from initially.

The problem:

let's say I was in the "/posts" page, and I clicked to login, so now I am on "/users/login".
- if the login is correct, or the login is incorrect and nothing is filled in the username textbox, everything works as expected (if it's correct I am redirected back to "/posts" otherwise I receive the "wrong username or password" message, I try to login again correctly and then I am redirected to "/posts";

- if the login is incorrect, and some text is filled in the username textbox, after the login I receive the "wrong username or password" message, which is good, but if I fill in the form again, no matter wheather it is correct or not, I get "You are not authorized to access that location." If I try to log for the third time, the login works, but I am redirected to "/users/posts" instead of "/posts" (the value for the redirect page, which is stored in a session, is still "/posts" ).

This is the code:

```
    function beforeFilter () {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        $this->Auth->allowedActions = array( 'confirmation');

        $this->Auth->fields = array(
            'username' => 'usr_username', 
            'password' => 'usr_password'
        );
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('User.usr_confirmed' => 1);

        if($this->action == 'signup') {  
            $this->Auth->authenticate = $this->User;  
        }
    }

function login () {
    if ( $this->Auth->user() ) {
        $this->redirect($this->Session->read('page'));
        exit();
    } 
}

function logout () {
    $this->Session->destroy('username');
    $this->redirect('/');
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like your form action is redirecting to a restricted area. check the form action attribute.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. My form action is pointing to /user/login, which is not restricted. 

It's strange, if I print the contents of $this->data['User'], it is empty after the second login (when the "You are not authorized.." message appears).

Comment: Ah, you were actually right.. I had $form->create('User', array('action' => 'login')), and when I replaced it with $form->create(null, array('url' => '/users/login')) it worked.. I thought the two meant the same thing..

Comment: they DO result in the same url unless Configure::write('Routing.admin', 'admin'); somehow messed it up for ya or you changed inflections.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the bottom of `app/views/layouts/default.ctp` to help debug the session:

```
<?php debug($session->read()); ?>
```

The `Auth.User` key will be filled with data when you are logged in, but, more importantly, the `Auth.redirect` key will containing the URL of the last restricted page visited, this is where `AuthComponent` plans on redirecting to once you log in.

Are you storing a restricted page's URL in the your session's `page` key?

If so, AuthComponent can provide that functionality already with its `Auth.redirect` key. All you need to do is link to the restricted page instead of the login page and `AuthComponent` will populate that key automatically and handle the redirect after login.

```
echo $html->link('Login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'profile'));
```

If not, then why not consider populating that key instead. Since `AuthComponent` already checks for and acts on this key, you might gain some free functionality.

In any event, here is what a custom `login` method should look like in your case, but if any of the advice above will work then you can simply leave out the `login` method all together and use the default functionality:

```
function login () {
    // log the user in
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        // your session redirect
        if ($this->Session->read('page')) {
            $this->redirect($this->Session->read('page'));
        }
        // auth's session redirect
        if ($this->Session->read('Auth.redirect')) {
            $this->redirect($this->Session->read('Auth.redirect'));
        }
        // default redirect
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
    }
}
```